# Get FaultCode from SoapFaultClientException in String

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, spring-ws

From the sample soap fault, How can I get the faultcode in String

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Fault xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
  <faultstring>The values from the client failed to pass validation.</faultstring>
  <detail>
    <Errors>
      <Error reason="Required on input.">
        <ErrorLocation>
          <Node level="1" name="MyElement"/>
          <Node level="2" name="MyField"/>
        </ErrorLocation>
        <Parameters/>
        <StackTrace/>
      </Error>
    </Errors>
  </detail>
</soap:Fault>
```

When we get the SoapFaultClientException the exception return FaultCode in QName
How can I get the FaultCode soap:Client in String

```
catch (SoapFaultClientException e) {
QName faultCode = e.getFaultCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
ex.getFaultCode().getLocalPart() will return Client
ex.getFaultCode().getPrefix() will return soap
```